# How to enable auto word completion in the MATLAB Editor?

Tags: matlab, editor, tab-completion

I can use auto word completion at the MATLAB command prompt by pressing tab, but I can not do that while using the Editor for an m file. Is there any way to use tab completion in the Editor?

Answer (score 22):

According to [this MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/03/22/tab-completion-in-the-matlab-r2010a-editor/), tab completion works in the Editor as it does in the Command Window for MATLAB R2010a, but you may have to turn it on in the **Keyboard Preferences** menu.

For older MATLAB versions, tab completion in the Editor only works for function names and variables that have *already been created in the workspace*. So, if you are writing a script with a variable `foobar`, and that variable hasn't yet been created in the workspace (i.e. Command Window), then `foobar` won't show up when using tab completion in the Editor. This was the case when I tested it in MATLAB 7.8.0 (R2009a).

Comment: Matlabs word completion is terrible. Very vey limited.

Answer (score 18):

When you are writing a code press key "TAB", see:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Tab completion works for function names that are on Matlab's path. It also works for variable names, if the variable exists in the workspace. Thus, while you code, it may be a good idea to evaluate commands as you write. This allows you to immediately check for errors, and it makes variables available for auto-completion.