# Matlab: How to activate autocomplete without Tab?

Tags: matlab, autocomplete

From
[How to enable auto word completion in the MATLAB Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223819/how-to-enable-auto-word-completion-at-matlab-editor)
I know that we can Tab to ask for autocomplete. However, this is kind tedious. In IDEs like rubymine, there is no need to ask for a autocomplete, the suggestion jumps out by itself.

And this is working on mobile device: http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlabmobile_android/ug/autocomplete.html. Is is possile to do it on desktop?

So how can I make the autocomplete `autoly`? without the need of Tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've searched that on the Internet before. But no results:( It seems that Tab is the only way to achieve complete on MATLAB desktop up till now. AUTOcomplete is available on the mobile version because of the inconvenience for one to type on a mobile phone MAYBE.